# Passing form data to the JSP without passing to the server

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, jsp

```
html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Landing</title> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
                                       initial-scale=1.0"> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
       
        <form name="testForm" action="move.jsp"> 
           <label><h1>Enter the data <h1/></label><br/> 
           <input type="text" name="DATA"><br/> 
           <input type="submit"> 
        </form> 
       
        <% out.println(DATA) %>  <!-- WRONG!! -->
    </body> 
</html>
```

Please ignore the action part

I am working on a spring mvc project and I have a problem. What I want is that, when the user clicks submit, we should not leave the page, we should just stay. But the values submitted would be used as a parameter to a function in the same page. Here, let's just say I want to print it, and that is the part that is wrongly entered.

What should I do to accomplish this? Please help

Comment: Scriptlets are java codes that are compiled within the sever. You can use Javascript to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can you give me an example where this problem is solved? A link maybe?

Comment: so the function you want to called is in java or it can be javascript ?

Comment: It is a java function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ajax` here when your submit button is clicked call this function and then using this call your ajax passed the value from your input to your server and then at your server side perform operation which you needed to do and then the result back to ajax .

Your form :

```
   <form name="testForm" action="move.jsp"> 
       <label><h1>Enter the data <h1/></label><br/> 
       <input type="text" name="DATA"><br/> 
       <input type="button" onclick="submit_values()">
                              <!--^^added this--> 
    </form> 
  <div id="result"><!--here data will come back--></div>
```

Then on click of your button `submit_values()` function will get called . i.e :

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <script>
    function submit_values() {
    //get input value
      var values = $("input[name='DATA']").val();
      console.log(values);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          values: values//passing to server
        },
        url: "Your_server_url",
        success: function(data) {
       alert(data);//this will display whatever server will return
      $("#result").html(data);//add response back to show
        }
      });
    
    }
</script>
```

Then at your server-side do like below :

```
String data =request.getParameter("values");//get value 
 String send_back = something(data);//call your function
out.println("DATA BACK"+send_back );//this will go back to ajax
```

Comment: What is the mapping for the server side part ?

Comment: if you are using servlet add that code in `doPost` method .Also , in `url` you need to give `url` of your servlet.